# facebook login android

Tags: android, facebook-api

quiero obtener los datos del perfil publico {email,id y la foto de perfil}, pero al iniciar mi aplicación se cae, a continuacion dejare mi codigo

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken()==null){
            String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
            email=data;
            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            nav_user.setText(email);
        }
        else{
           GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(
                        JSONObject object,
                        GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        user.setEmail(response.getJSONObject().get("email").toString());
                        user.setName(response.getJSONObject().get("name").toString());
                        user.setImageUri(response.getJSONObject().get("picture").toString());
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

            String correos=user.getEmail();

            NavigationView navigationsView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            View hView =  navigationsView.getHeaderView(0);
            TextView nav_user = (TextView)hView.findViewById(R.id.txtMail);
            nav_user.setText(correos);

            ImageView fperfil=(ImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            fperfil.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(user.getImageUri()));

        }
```

y este es mi logcat

```
11-03 16:15:11.755 30076-30076/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                   Process: com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp, PID: 30076
                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.facebook.AccessToken com.facebook.GraphRequest.getAccessToken()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945)
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.facebook.AccessToken com.facebook.GraphRequest.getAccessToken()' on a null object reference
                                                                                       at com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:103)
                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:945) 
                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:740)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás considerando varios pasos cómo por ejemplo la existencia de los keys..
y tus key "picture" no existe en FB 4.5

Esto debería servirte para poder obtener la foto de perfil, nombre y apellido

```
private void obtenerDatos( JSONObject object) {
    String id_fb = "";
    String foto = "";
    String nombre = "";
    String apellido = "";
    String email = "";
    try {
        id_fb = object.getString("id");

        try {
            URL profile_pic = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/" + id_fb + "/picture?width=200&height=150");
            Log.i("profile_pic", profile_pic + "");
            foto = profile_pic.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (object.has("first_name"))
            nombre = object.getString("first_name");
        if (object.has("last_name"))
            apellido = object.getString("last_name");
        if (object.has("email"))
            email = object.getString("email");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("FOTO", foto);
    Log.d("NOMBRE", nombre);
    Log.d("APELLIDO", apellido);
    Log.d("EMAIL", email);

    //GUARDAR CON PREFENCIA
    SharedPreferences preferencia = getSharedPreferences("preferencia_fb", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencia.edit();
    editor.putString("foto_fb", foto);
    editor.putString("nombre_fb", nombre);
    editor.putString("apellido_fb", apellido);
    editor.putString("email_fb", email);
    editor.commit(); //COMMIT

    //en este caso ya tengo una instancia de preferencia y siempre recuerda que las preferencias crean pequeños archivos en los móviles
    //haciendo que "preferencia_fb" sea el nombre de mi archivo debes ingresar siempre "preferencia_fb" para acceceder a sus variables que tenga
    String foto_guardada = preferencia.getString("foto_fb", "no se recibió nada"); //ASÍ LLAMAS UNA VARIABLE DE PREFERENCIA, EL SEGUNDO PARÁMETRO ES PARA VALIDAD NULLIDAD
}
```

Comment: gracias, pero soy nuevo en esto y no entiendo como obtener las variables desde ese código, ya que como obtengo el json del metodo y como los puedo guardar en variables locales, esa es mi duda, si pudieses ayudarme por favor

Comment: Ok te voy a ayudar pero dime sabes usar preferencias o sqlite ?

Comment: ninguna de ambas, sql se, pero nunca he trabajado con sqlite

Comment: tengo 2 clases una login y main activity, la idea es obtener los datos desde el main activity para colocarlos en una navigation drawer, pero he estado buscando ejemplos o documentancion y de la version 4.5 de la api de facebook  no he encontrado mucho, o algo que entienda, la verdad, el boton de inicio de sesion ya me funciona, pero la obtencion de los datos es lo que me falta

Comment: Ya mira debes aprender ambos ya que te van a servir en android siempre, estos sirven para guardar información en los móviles. Ahora te recomiendo esta página http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/android/

Comment: la idea no es guardala, solo leerla, tengo una base de datos mssql conectada a la app para las operaciones, donde necesito guardar datos, aunque agradesco toda ayuda :)

Comment: Ya tengo que salir te dejé un ejemplo de Preferencia para que puedas guardar y luego llamarlas, de todas formas si no entiendes puedes buscar  información en la página que te di...